# Launching activity from notification , app is going through latest activity onResume

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have problem with notifications. It all works well launching correct activity from notification.

Problem is that when new activity is launched from notification and app has been in background. Then first the latest activity is loaded (on Resume()) and after that intended activity is loaded. In `onResume` I'm checking the session expiration. And when its expired user will be taken to login. And in the latest activity i don't have notification extras.

Is there possibility to skip latest activity `onResume` when opening notification and going straight to the intended activity.

```
    PendingIntent createContentIntent(Context appContext, NotificationData data) {
    Intent notificationIntent = createNotificationIntent(appContext, data);
    if (notificationIntent == null) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent();
    }
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Bundle extras = createBundle();
    extras.putSerializable(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_DATA, data);
    notificationIntent.putExtras(extras);

    return createPendingIntentActivity(appContext, notificationIntent);
}
```

Comment: Wanted to add that, it seems it happens when notification is opened from lock screen. Otherwise right activity is opened without resuming last activity.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your new activity manifest to include custom task affinity, and consider changing launchMode to singleTop to prevent creating duplicates of the activity:

```
<activity
            android:name=".your_activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=":task_2"/>
```

Also include `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in your launch intent.

Comment: Ill give it a try and let you know how did it work out. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: I used this approach and now when i click on the notification new instance of app is opened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that Android is bringing your existing task to the foreground and then (obviously) resuming the top `Activity` in the task BEFORE it creates the `Activity` from the `Notification`. This sounds like an Android bug.

Anyway, to get around this, you could try having the `Notification` launch an `Activity` into a different task. To do this, set `taskAffinity=""` on the `Activity` that the `Notification` starts. The `Activity` started by the `Notification` would then have to start another `Activity` that will run in the task with the rest of your app. Hopefully this would all happen after the phone is unlocked so that you don't see this `onResume()` problem.

If you need more help, please post the code from `createNotificationIntent()` and `createPendingIntentActivity()` and the relevant parts of your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it seems with this implementation will give me more than one instance of app when i check running apps. But investigating this issue further it seems this could be normal activity cycle. 

Im thinking that what could i do , is that im gonna move the code that checks my session away from resume and implement onSavedInstanceState correctly and move session controlling to onCreate and into requests. So then i will not be interupted in onResume state and will be directed to intended activity.

Comment: Yes, you will have to play around to get this to work the way you want to. You could have the Notification `Activity` short-lived, so that it just launches the correct `Activity` in the normal app task and then goes away. You should also add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the manifest extry for that `Activity`. In this way, you wouldn't have multiple instances in the "recent apps" list.

Comment: Thanks...gonna try but i think app should be able to keep working normally. With short-lived state - case when app is not running and you'll open notification then the task will disapear if youll put it to background. And its pretty confusing.

Comment: You misunderstand. Clicking the Notification (if the app is not running) should start a new task with the `NotificationActivity`. This `Activity` should then launch the desired `Activity` into the app task (whatever `Activity` you are using now from the `Notification`. This will start an `Activity` in the real app task which will be shown in the list of recent tasks. I'm simply suggesting that you use this 2-step process to get around the bug where Android is bringing an existing task to the foreground and calling `onResume()` unnecessarily.

Comment: oh, i get it now..gonna try to implement this way :)